# PHPUnit installation blues

Tags: php, installation, phpunit, pear

I have installed [PHPUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit) by the PHPUnit Manual, *[Chapter 3. Installing PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html)*,

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de    
pear channel-discover components.ez.no    
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com    
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Now my PHPUnit folder looks like:

```
> pwd
/usr/share/php/PHPUnit
> ll
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 2011-05-19 15:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 2011-05-19 15:13 ../
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 2011-05-19 15:13 Extensions/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 2011-05-19 15:12 Framework/
```

As you can see, no executables. Command `phpunit` does not exist.

OS: Ubuntu 11.04.

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable should be `/usr/bin/phpunit`. Or in `pear config-show | grep execu` for that matter.

It case it's not try:

```
pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/phpunit
```

and check again. It should fix the broken installation.

Also make sure you are using **`pear version 1.9.2`**. If it that might be the problem.

Run `pear install pear/pear` to fix that or if that doesn't work out (and installing phpunit still gives you errors):

```
pear install --force --alldeps pear/pear
```

Comment: It gives "PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/bin" but there is no /usr/bin/phpunit. alldeps didn't fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't fix the problem? The only other thing that could be an issue is the pear installer it's self. Check it's version and update (also do all channel-discovers if it asks you to do so)

Comment: Hm, warning: phpunit/PHPUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.9.1

Comment: Yes, after upgrade like on http://superuser.com/questions/55055/how-to-install-an-updated-version-of-pear-phpunit-on-ubuntu and your alldeps command it works. Thanks.